# CSV writing: a list of 200+ dicts, or one list/dict + append?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a program that will create and fill (with either generated or scraped data) a rather long .csv file.

After spending some time thinking of how to structure this and looking up examples online, I decided to try creating a list of dictionaries, of the type:

```
[{col_1 : data_1, col_2 : data_3, col_3 : data_3}, {col_1 : data_1 ...}]
```

,where the keys will be written as column headers, and each new line populated with data from each individual dictionary. But then I thought, this feels cumbersome.

Is this the right way to go about this, or is it better to simply use one dictionary/list, and fill it with data -> append -> fill with new data -> append, etc.?

- To clarify, I mean appending new lines to the .csv file, effectively generating it line by line, rather than generating the entire file in one go.

Comment: This is data-dependent. One good solution is [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `csv` module has `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` classes (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)) which make reading and writing CVS files with rows represented a dictionaries very easy.

Comment: @Alex I just had a brief look at pandas documentation, and it appears to me that a better solution is to make a dictionary of lists, convert it into a DataFrame, and export that to CSV. Thank you, I haven't considered looking outside the default Python box!